# Problem with Pyinstaller with incorrect configuration or dependency after packaging

Tags: python, installation, pyinstaller, python-packaging

I'm trying to package the attached Python application into an executable using PyInstaller. However, after packaging the application, I ran into an issue where the application failed to generate the expected output and instead opened multiple instances of the GUI(Screenshot attached).
I understand this is common when packaging Python applications with PyInstaller with incorrect configurations or dependencies not being properly included in the packaged executable or just could be that the application is not well scripted to be packaged.

Can anyone assist in filling in the missing piece? Thank you in anticipation

[image]